# Prevent autofolding when pasting with <S-p> in indent mode

Tags: vim

I am in `foldmethod=indent` mode with all plugins disabled.  Consider a text file like the following:

```
- some list
  - list item 1
  - list item 2
```

If I `yyp` on line 2 of the file (the line containing item 1), everything works as expected and I get:

```
- some list
  - list item 1
  - list item 1
  - list item 2
```

However, if I `yy<S-p>` on the same file (to paste above the current line instead of below it), vim correctly pastes the line, but incorrectly autofolds at the same time, so I am left with:

[image: folded lines]

How can I prevent this from happening?

*Note: It happens only when foldmethod is indent*